# Write CASE condition for one column in the Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a query in which, I want to apply `CASE` condition. This is my query:

```
Select 
    a.mkey, a.party_name, a.doc_no Inward_No, 
    c.type_desc Doc_Type, a.ref_no, 
    convert(varchar(25),a.ref_date,103) Ref_date,
    a.Inward_amt, b.first_name + ' ' + b.last_name ToUser --- here
from 
    inward_doc_tracking_hdr a
inner join 
    user_mst b on a.To_User = b.mkey
inner join 
    type_mst_a c on a.doc_type = c.master_mkey  
                 and a.mkey =227423
```

What I want is: if I get `ToUser` as `NULL` then I want to take `Last_To_User` in place of that.

How to do this in SQL Server?

Comment: If any of the answers worked, plz accept it as answer and upvote :)

Comment: Did you find an answer @NK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this - just use `ISNULL` around your concatenation of first and last name:

```
Select 
    a.mkey, a.party_name, a.doc_no Inward_No, 
    c.type_desc Doc_Type, a.ref_no, 
    convert(varchar(25),a.ref_date,103) Ref_date,
    a.Inward_amt, 
    -- if the first_name+last_name is NULL, then take Last_To_User instead
    ISNULL(b.first_name + ' ' + b.last_name, Last_To_User) ToUser 
from 
    inward_doc_tracking_hdr a
inner join 
    user_mst b on a.To_User = b.mkey
inner join 
    type_mst_a c on a.doc_type = c.master_mkey  
                 and a.mkey =227423
```

Answer (score 0):

Case is not needed you can use the coalesce function that will return the first non null value:

```
b.first_name + ' ' + b.last_name + coalesce(Touser,Last_To_User)
```

Comment: getting error as **Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'coalesce'.**

Comment: edited my answer, you got a syntax error with that ?

Comment: getting error as **Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'Touser'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'Touser'.**

Comment: seems that the column is named to_user, not touser (if I look the end of your query).

Comment: yes, I resolved that. but now I dont get value of `last_to_user` iff i pass whose `To_User` is NULL

Comment: Also when I take `to_user` I get error as **Error converting data type varchar to numeric.**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `b.first_name + ' ' + b.last_name` use the following:

```
CASE
 WHEN b.first_name IS NULL THEN b.first_name + ' ' + b.last_name
 ELSE Last_To_User
END
```

Comment: is your syntax correct ? I get error as **Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IS'.**

Comment: `IIF` is a **new function** in SQL Server **2012** and thus *not available* to the OP since he's on SQL Server **2005** .....

Comment: any other way guys to achieve this ?

Comment: @marc_s: any simple way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite clear now so i'll tell you this, you use inner join to join table user_mst and the condition is To_User so you already filter the rows that have To_User is null, you know, Null can't connect to anything, so try to make it left join

```
Select a.mkey, a.party_name, a.doc_no Inward_No, c.type_desc Doc_Type, a.ref_no, 
    convert(varchar(25),a.ref_date,103) Ref_date,
            a.Inward_amt, 
            case when To_User is null then Last_To_User
            else b.first_name + ' ' + b.last_name end as ToUser --- here
        from inward_doc_tracking_hdr a
    left join user_mst b
on a.To_User = b.mkey
        inner join type_mst_a c
    on a.doc_type = c.master_mkey   
    and a.mkey =227423
```

Comment: yes `last_to_user` is a column. But when I take value for NULL it doesn't show the `last_to_user` value.

Comment: @NK Of course it won't work, check your ToUser column, you use b.first_name + ' ', so it will have a blank anyway, i'll edit my answer to make it be "when the ToUser be blank it will be Last_To_User"

Comment: Not correct, you are checking for first_name and last_name for NULL. I want to check for To_User if NULL then take last_To_User. Otherwise take To_User only.

Comment: @NK as i said, To_User won't be null forever dude, you hard code an ' ' in it. so it will have a blank forever. what you can do is to check whether the first name and last name are null.

Comment: My To_User will be NULL sometime. for that Only I want to use the case condition. I tried like this **Select a.mkey, a.party_name, a.doc_no Inward_No, c.type_desc Doc_Type, a.ref_no, 
    convert(varchar(25),a.ref_date,103) Ref_date,
            a.Inward_amt, 
            case when a.To_User is null then a.Last_To_User
            else a.To_User end as ToUser 
        from inward_doc_tracking_hdr a
    inner join user_mst b
on a.To_User = b.mkey
 inner join type_mst_a c on a.doc_type = c.master_mkey  and a.mkey =227413**  but when I take for To_User NULL it does not work

Comment: @NK Oh,so there is a column named To_User? lol, you named the new column ToUser so i thought you mean the ToUser is null all the time. ok, i ll update my answer for another time XD

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116057/discussion-between-n-k-and-raffaello-d-huke).

Comment: come on chat, we will discuss their

Comment: i got the answer for that, If u come on chat I will show u

Answer (score 0):

I think your post confused most people, and potentially me as well. After reading the comments it seems you want to take To_User (the column, not your aliased column of `b.first_name + ' ' + b.last_name`) if it `IS NOT NULL`, but if it `IS NULL` then you you want `Last_to_User`.Thus you should use `COALESCE` like this:

`COALESCE(To_User,Last_To_User,'')`

This will give you the FIRST `NOT NULL` value in the list. So, If `To_User IS NOT NULL` it will be returned. If it `IS NULL` then `Last_To_User` will be returned, unless it is also `NULL` in which case a blank will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm less confused than anybody else, I'm no expert and this might seem pretty rudimentary but my simplest answer is;

```
WITH QUERY1 AS (

Select 
a.mkey, 
a.party_name, 
a.doc_no AS Inward_No, 
c.type_desc 
Doc_Type, 
a.ref_no, 
convert(varchar(25),a.ref_date,103) AS Ref_date,
a.Inward_amt, 
b.first_name + ' ' + b.last_name AS ToUser --- here
from 
inward_doc_tracking_hdr a
inner join 
user_mst b on a.To_User = b.mkey
inner join 
type_mst_a c on a.doc_type = c.master_mkey  
             and a.mkey =227423
             )
SELECT *,
   CASE WHEN ToUser IS NULL
   THEN Last_To_User
   ELSE ToUser
FROM QUERY1
```